# Mathematica Can Find the Primitive Function But It Cannot Find the Closed Form for Corresponding Definite Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions

Consider the following function

```
f = 1/2 (-3 + 4 u) Sqrt[-u (1 + u) (-1 - u + u^2)]
```

where it is assumed that

```
phi = (1+Sqrt[5])/2
1 < u < phi
```

Then I want to find

```
Integrate[f,{u,1,phi}]
```

But Mathematica cannot find the exact value of the above definite integral. It gets surprising when I found that it can find the primitive function

```
Integrate[f,u]
```

Can someone tell me that why this happens?

Comment: *Mathematica* does not really do too well with cleanly evaluating elliptic integrals; some amount of analytical hand-holding can be needed.

Comment: the antiderivative returned has a complex part that blows up at `phi`

Comment: @george2079: Thanks for clarification. Can you specify that part please. :) I cannot spot it. And does it mean that the integral diverges!? I don't think so!

Comment: `NIntegrate` gives an answer with an infinitesimal complex part which you can drop `0.773512+4.17354*10^-26 I`.

Comment: I just observed that numerically, `Integrate[f, u] /. u -> phi // N` throws an error.  This: `(Integrate[f, u] /. u -> (phi - 10^-10)) - (Integrate[f, u] /. 
    u -> 1) // N` gives the same result as `NIntegrate` so I believe the integal converges, its just an issue with the particular form of the antiderivative.

Comment: @JackLaVigne: Thanks but I want the closed form not the numerical value. :)

Comment: The solution to `Integrate[f, u]` has the denominator, `(2 (1 + Sqrt[5]) Sqrt[-1 + Sqrt[5] - 2/u] (1 + u) (1 + u - u^2))`, which vanishes at `u -> (1 + Sqrt[5])/2`.  Of course, this does not mean that the solution itself is singular there.

Comment: @H.R. Can you explain what you need to do with the closed form that you cannot do with the numerical approximation? Perhaps somebody might have a suggestion to get around that limitation instead. As an aside note, your integrand and its integral are complex over the range of interest, but their imaginary part is constant: [`Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@Integrate[f, u], {u, 1, phi}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Re", "Im"}]`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4iIAo.png).

Comment: @MarcoB: The integrand is real when $1<u<\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. I am sure! :) I just want the closed form as I prefer them to numerical values! :) Also, I was interested to know that why Mathematica does not compute the definite integral in the closed form. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the question, the definite integral `Integrate[f,{u, 1, phi}]` returns unevaluated, although the indefinite integral `Integrate[f,u]` does not.  Nonetheless, the definite integral can be determined with a bit of work.  To begin,

```
s = FullSimplify[Integrate[f, u], 1 < u < phi]
(* 1/2 ((Sqrt[u + 2 u^2 - u^4] (1 + 2 u (-1 + (-1 + u) u)))/(2 u) + 
   (1/(4 (1 + Sqrt[5] - 2 u)))Sqrt[(2 + u - Sqrt[5] u)/(1 + 2 u - u^3)] 
   (Sqrt[(1 + u) (1 + Sqrt[5] + (3 + Sqrt[5]) u)] ((-2 + (-1 + Sqrt[5]) u) 
   EllipticE[ArcSin[Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[5] + 2/u]/(Sqrt[2] 5^(1/4))], 
       1/2 (5 + Sqrt[5])] + (1 + Sqrt[5] - 2 u) 
   EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[5] + 2/u]/(Sqrt[2] 5^(1/4))], 
       1/2 (5 + Sqrt[5])]) - 4 Sqrt[-(1 + Sqrt[5] - 2 u) (-1 - 2 u + u^3)]
   EllipticPi[1/2 (5 - Sqrt[5]), ArcSin[Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[5] + 2/u]/(Sqrt[2] 5^(1/4))], 
   1/2 (5 + Sqrt[5])])) *)
```

Plotting `s` shows that it is well-behaved over the region of interest.

```
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[s]], {u, 1, phi}]
```

[image]

Hence, the definite integral is simply `s` at `phi` minus `s` at `1`.  Unfortunately, `s /. u -> phi` returns `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>`.  (This is because several of the terms in `s` evaluate to `0/0` at `u -> phi`.)  Moreover, extending the `Plot` beyond `phi` shows that `s` is discontinuous there.  Although it is impossible to know precisely why the definite integral of `f` returns unevaluated, it seems likely that one or both of these issues prevents the definite integral from returning evaluated.

There are a number of ways, however, to evaluate `s` at `phi`.  For instance,

```
s /. ArcSin[z_] :> Simplify[ArcSin[z] /. u -> phi];
```

which evaluates `ArcSin` to `Pi/2` and simplifies the elliptic integrals, followed by

```
Limit[%, u -> phi, Direction -> 1] // FullSimplify
(* 1/8 (Sqrt[2 (1 + Sqrt[5])] EllipticK[1/2 (5 + Sqrt[5])] - 
   Sqrt[2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])] (EllipticE[1/2 (5 + Sqrt[5])] + 
   2 EllipticPi[1/2 (5 - Sqrt[5]), 1/2 (5 + Sqrt[5])])) *)
```

Note that `Direction -> 1` is necessary to handle the discontinuity mentioned above.  (The seemingly simpler `Limit[s, u -> phi, Direction -> 1] // FullSimplify` returns unevaluated, and `Series[s, {u, phi, 0}]` runs for hours without returning.)

Evaluating `s` at the lower limit of integration works without these difficulties.

```
Simplify[s /. u -> 1]
(* (1/(8 Sqrt[2]))(-4 + (1/(-1 + Sqrt[5])) 2 Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[5]] ((-3 + Sqrt[5]) 
   EllipticE[ArcSin[Sqrt[3 + Sqrt[5]]/(Sqrt[2] 5^(1/4))], 1/2 (5 + Sqrt[5])] + 
   (-1 + Sqrt[5]) EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[3 + Sqrt[5]]/(Sqrt[2] 5^(1/4))], 
   1/2 (5 + Sqrt[5])]) - 4 Sqrt[-1 + Sqrt[5]]
   EllipticPi[1/2 (5 - Sqrt[5]), ArcSin[Sqrt[3 + Sqrt[5]]/(Sqrt[2] 5^(1/4))], 
   1/2 (5 + Sqrt[5])]) *)
```

Evaluating the two expressions numerically (with `N`) returns values equal to the endpoint values in the `Plot` above, confirming the accuracy of the analysis.  Taking the difference of these two expressions yields an analytical expression for the definite integral.  Of course,

```
N[%% - %] // N // Chop
(* 0.773512 *)
```

yields the same value as `NIntegrate[f, {u, 1, phi}] // Chop`.